# Maxwell equations invariant under Lorentz transformation but not Galilean transformations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, symmetry, maxwell-equations, galilean-relativity

Why Maxwell equations are not invariant under Galilean transformations, but invariant under Lorentz transformations? What is the deep physical meaning behind it?

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit demonstration of these properties, or what....I mean, that set of equation simple *has* those mathematical properties. It's sort of like asking why a square ninety degree angles and not sixty degree one. The deep physical meaning is that physics is Einsteinian and not Galilean.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest answer is that Galilean transformations do not preserve the invariance of light's speed but Lorentz transformations do. Are you looking for something deeper?

Answer (score 3):

It tells you that the phenomena of electromagnetism are inherently relativistic and unlike mechanics there is no "Newtonian" low-velocity non-relativistic limit. Hence the equations have Lorentz structure built into them.

Comment: You can make a quasistatic approximation when the timescale of the sources $T$ and the size of the system $L$ are such that $L/T \ll c$, or $L/c \ll T$. This means that the field propagates through the entire system much faster than the sources vary. This is a non-relativistic approximation since we get action at a distance. Of course, we can't capture all EM phenomena in this approximation. In particular, radiation is usually studied in the opposite regime $r/c \gg T$ where $r$ is the distance to the source.

Answer (score 1):

This is because electromagnetic radiation is a manifestation of some properties of the spacetime, consequently it has to be invariant under those transformations which preserves the spacetime interval invariant.

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrangian of a free electro-magnetic field already suggests Lorentz symmetry not Galilean symmetry as elaborated in the following:

The Lagrangian of electro-magnetic field is $L=\frac{1}{2}(E^{2}-B^{2})$,
with $E=-\partial_{t}A-\partial\phi$ and $B=\nabla\times A$. Defining
the four vector potentials as $A_{\mu}=(\phi,-A)$, the Lagrangian
can be also written as:
\begin{align}
S= & \int-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu},
\end{align}
with $\eta^{\alpha\mu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1\\
 & -1\\
 &  & -1\\
 &  &  & -1
\end{array}\right)$ the Minkovski metric. Hereafter, Greek letter used to denote spacetime indices ranging from 0,1,2,3. To see the above action is invariant under
Lorentz boost but not Galilean boost, we can ask a more general question:
what is the symmetry transformation of the above action. If restricted
to linear symmetry transformations, $A_{\mu}\rightarrow\Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu}A_{\nu}$
with $\Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu}$ constant, the action is transformed as:

\begin{align}
S\rightarrow & \int-\frac{1}{4}(\Lambda_{\alpha}^{\sigma}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\Lambda_{\mu}^{\delta})(\Lambda_{\beta}^{\gamma}\eta^{\beta\nu}\Lambda_{\nu}^{\tau})F_{\sigma\gamma}F_{\delta\tau}.
\end{align}
For symmetry transformations, the Lagrangian can only be changed up to
a total divergence term. A more strict condition is that $L$ is unchanged.
Denoting $(\Lambda_{\alpha}^{\sigma}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\Lambda_{\mu}^{\delta})=\eta^{\prime\sigma\delta}$,
it indicates that:
\begin{align}
\eta^{\sigma\delta}=\eta^{\prime\sigma\delta}= & \Lambda_{\alpha}^{\sigma}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\Lambda_{\mu}^{\delta}.
\end{align}
It is well known that linear tranformations $\Lambda$ satisfying
the above relation forms the Poincare group. It is also easy to check
that Galilean boost does not satisfy the above relation.

If coupled to a charge particle, the Poincare symmetry of the free electro-magnetic field also put constraint on the dynamics of the charged particle. In the presence
of a moving point charge, the action is added by another term:
\begin{align*}
S= & -\frac{1}{4}\int\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}+q\int d\tau A_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu},
\end{align*}
where $\dot{x}^{\mu}=(\dot{t},\dot{r})$ is the four velocity of the
piont, $q$ is the charge it carries and $\tau$ is some fixed parameter
describing the point charge trajectory $x^{\mu}(\tau)$. If the point
charge does not break the Poincare symmetry of the free electro-magnetic
field, $\dot{x}^{\mu}$ should transforms as $\dot{x}^{\mu}\rightarrow\Lambda_{\nu}^{-1\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}$
such that the term $A_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}$ is unchanged. If the point
charge has its own action $\int d\tau L_{q}(x^{\mu},\dot{x}^{\mu})$,
this in turn put constrains on the possible form of $L_{q}$. The
Newtonian kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^{2}$ is not invariant
under the Poincare group while the relativistic $\sqrt{\dot{t}^{2}-\dot{r}^{2}}$
satisfies the symmetry requirement.